# Subtracting a vector from a specific column in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have a matrix with 7 columns and 146 rows. I have a vector with 146 characters and I am trying to subtract that vector from the first column of the matrix.

I also need to subtract 65 from every number in the 21-45th rows in the 4th column, but I have not been able to figure out how to single out certain rows in specific columns.

I have attempted to use the sweep function for the subtraction of the vector, but every way that I have tried will not give me anything other than NA.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible data set that exemplifies your problem, perhaps by copying and pasting the output of `dput(mydata)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way using mtcars as an example.  You merely have to change the df name and the row/column references.  Note that the cars names are row names and not a column:

```
set.seed(7)
cars <- mtcars
head(cars)
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
vec <- sample(-10:10, 32, replace = TRUE)
vec
# [1] -1  8 -4 -9  4 -3 -8 -3  4 -3  1  8  9 -3  7  4 -5  5 10 -7  0 -5 -9 -7 -5  0 -3  6  3 -7 -8  2
cars[1] <- cars[1] + vec
head(cars)
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4         20.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag     29.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710        18.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Hornet 4 Drive    12.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
# Hornet Sportabout 22.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
# Valiant           15.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
cars[20:25, 4] <- cars[20:25, 4] - 65
cars[20:25, ]
#                   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Toyota Corolla   26.9   4  71.1   0 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
# Toyota Corona    21.5   4 120.1  32 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
# Dodge Challenger 10.5   8 318.0  85 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
# AMC Javelin       6.2   8 304.0  85 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
# Camaro Z28        6.3   8 350.0 180 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
# Pontiac Firebird 14.2   8 400.0 110 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
```